# Accessing another user's files

Tags: permissions, files, group

I have a file `"abc"` with permissions 440 .The owner of this file is `"root"` and the group of this file is `"groupabc"` . I have a user `"user1`" .Is their anyway I can see the contents of files `"abc"` using the user `"user1"` ?

I don't have the root password.

What comes to my mind is that since file `"abc"` belongs to the group `"groupabc"` ,so if I can add the user `"user1"` to the group `"groupabc"`. I should be able to view the contents of the file `"abc"`. I tried command `usermod` ,but since I don't have the `sudo` access ,It didn't work.Is their anyway I can view the contents of the file `"abc"`.

Comment: Hi...Is there anything called `guest` group in unix. I see the contents of /etc/groups as below.Does this have any special meaning ?             `guest:x:1014:`                                                                      `groupabc:x:1024:guest`

Comment: You could easily create a group called `guest` but it probably wouldn't have any special significance - it's just a normal group.  How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: You will need root to give you access (either as root, or as the owner of the file). That's the whole point of permissions.

Comment: The group administrator can also add you to the group, if there have one.

Comment: You should ask the person that administers your machine.  They will have root access.  Otherwise, the `/tmp` folder may be used for sharing files with other users temporarily, as the folder name suggests.

Comment: Is their any concept of `open group` in unix, I mean a group that is open to all and any user can assign itself to that group.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to allow `user1` to read file `abc` whose permissions and ownership attributes are as you describe, you need to do one of the following:

- change the file ownership (so that `user1` or a group that contains `user1` owns the file), or
- change the permissions so the file is world readable, allowing everyone including `user1` to read it, or
- add `user1` to group `groupabc`.

Unfortunately, you need superuser (`root`) privileges to do any of the above, so without that you are out of luck within the constraints of the conventional Unix access control scheme.

Since your question is "is there any way ...?", there are other more indirect ways.  You could ask a human in control of `root` for permission to read the file.  Assuming the file system is not encrypted and you have physical access, you could reboot into another OS where you do have `root` access (e.g. a live CD / USB) and mount the file system there.  Shadier methods probably exist as well.

Comment: Is their any concept of `open group` in unix, I mean a group that is open to all and any user can assign itself to that group.

Comment: @user1743613 No, there is no such thing.  Only root can add users to groups.

Comment: Well, there is on systems that support gshadow. Then, it's just a matter of doing `gpasswd that-group` (as `root` or any _administrator_ of that group), provide with an empty password. Then, any user can start a new process with that-group as the gid with the `newgrp` or `sg` commands.