# Unix files system related puzzle

Tags: linux, filesystems

There was a question in one of quiz conducted one year back. I was attempting to solve this question and got stuck. All the other were programming related but this one was a Unix file permissions related Stuff. Following is the scenario.

You will be given a login and a password to a SSH server. `ssh your-username@server-addr`

Your task is to look for a file named `/home/abc/chekme` and retrieve the contents.

When logged in to the ssh remote server doing an `ls -l` shows 0 files, which shows that the login given has no permissions but on doing `ls -l` for the above mentioned file it can be seen that Read permission is given to the root user and a group and the name of the group is `chekme`.

I can't read the file because I don't have the permission and am not a member of that group. On exploring the `/etc/group` file I found out that there is a group named `chekme` and only one user is added to that group. The user name is `guest`

From here I tried changing my guid to that of the group, adding myself to the group, doing a `su` as the user `guest` but none of it worked since the first two required `root` access and `su` to guest required the password of that user.

How do I proceed now ?

Actual question with login creds :

> File : /home/hacker-weekly/abacus
>
> So, you have to read the file '/home/hacker-weekly/abacus' and submit
> the file content here.
>
> If you haven't got your login credentials, get it by clicking on the
> button 'Get Login Credential' below. Then you can login into the
> machine by running following command:
>
> ssh "your-username"@"server-addr"
>
> Hint: Think all about file permission in a UNIX-based system.
>
> Login
> credentials Server:
> ec2-175-41-164-254.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com Username:
> ashwinscongo Password: ab12d6H

The group name is abacus, the user in that group is guest. Tried /etc/passwrd, couldn't make out anything.

Comment: Obviously i do not have sudo or root access.

Comment: User `guest`'s password is often `guest` or blank. Did you try that?

Comment: yup. Its neither blank nor guest. My another doubt is is it the useual guest user or could it be a user created with the name of guest ?

Comment: You did try ssh guest@ (instead of su/sudo)?

Comment: You mean logout and try loging in as guest@ with ssh ? i tried that, it requested for guest's password

Comment: You could also try `newgrp` to see if the `chekme` group has a password.

Comment: @0v3rc10ck3d: Check the /etc/passwd file to see if the user has a shell attached (that isn't /nologin). You can also check the user number to see what sort of user it is.

Comment: Also, what kind of test was this? Were you supposed to find a vulnerability on the machine, and exploit it?

Comment: @Satanicpuppy how does user number determine anything ? and i did check etc/passwrd file. guest does have a shell

Comment: Could we get access to the server (is this an open quiz)? It would be easier if we could play with it directly.

Comment: @0v3rc10ck3d Some times people get tricky and change "root" to some other username. The user with the user ID of "0" is the root user, regardless of the name. It's unlikely, but they're being tricky, so it's worth checking.

Comment: I changed the details since i did not want to refer to the website directly that organised the quiz. Anyway it was a coding competition on a website called hackerearth.com. Is it ok if i update just with the whole actual question and my login ?

Comment: No need for your login, if we want, we can go do it ourselves :)

Comment: Its generated by them neways :) i updated the description. I have been banging my head for a day and a half now. Wanted to do it on my own but couldn and nor could i resist myself to stay without an answer.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy couldnt figre out much with that

Comment: @derobert no the group has a password. tried that too initially.

Comment: It can't be solved from your post, but with ssh access it [isn't too hard](http://www.hackerearth.com/users/Tobu/). It's more indirect than the obvious suggestions; think about the rest of the permission bits.

Comment: @Tobu If the sticky and directory bits aren't relevant, and the file is not executable, I can only think of the special setuid and setgid bits. Are they relevant to the puzzle? [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kgplug/MaZyTnEPwCY), someone said they solved it by logging into guest, "a tricky part", and "not really
relevant to the above discussion about permissions".

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55948/accessing-another-users-files

Comment: Meta discussion: [Is solving a CTF too localized?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/is-solving-a-ctf-too-localized) Solving this exercise isn't directly about file permissions. This question isn't useful except to someone solving this CTF.

Comment: Just found out about this SE site, codegolf, this would seem to fit into that site much better, http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @slm I'm pretty sure this would be off-topic on codegolf. It's not a *programming* puzzle.

Comment: @derobert - so we have no home in the SE community for this type of Q? That seems wrong to me. Perhaps if the Q were written as to what types of methods could one employ to approach solving this type of problem?

Comment: @slm We have no home in the SE community for all kinds of questions—and [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) for setting up new sites. That said, its possible these questions could fit in here.

Comment: @derobert - yeah I know the SE sites only fit certain classes of Q&A's 8-). I'd be inclined to change the structure of this Q to make it fit. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @slm I... don't know how to restructure this question. It seems to be completely specific to this particular game. (E.g., if your system had weird suid executables, we'd not tell you to use `find`—we'd tell you to format and reinstall). I'm also somewhat uncomfortable with this question more-or-less being (at least, as the answered turned out to be) 'give me teh cheat codes, plz'.

Comment: @derobert - yeah that's why I tried to keep it vague and not provide the specifics. Oh well I guess we'll close it then. I'd already voted to close, I think Gilles had done so as well.

Comment: And now HackerEarth is spamming us. No way to unsubscribe or delete the account.

Comment: And thats y i gave my account details.

Answer (score 6):

Approach:

```
$ ls -l /home/hacker-weekly/abacus
-r--r----- 1 root abacus 373 Nov 12  2012 /home/hacker-weekly/abacus
$ id
uid=1554(gilles) gid=1555(gilles) groups=1555(gilles)
```

So we need to either gain root permissions or gain `abacus` group permissions. But how?

Hint (step 1): <sub>How do you elevate privileges?</sub>

Full solution (step 1):

> Look for setuid or setgid executables that shouldn't be there:
>      find / -xdev -perm /4000 -ls 2>/dev/null
>  There are two likely candidates: /usr/local/abacus and /usr/bin/hacker-weekly-abacus. Running the latter prints out an SSH private key.

Hint (step 2): <sub>The obvious way to use this file is to log into some other account. Which account?</sub>

Full solution (step 2):

> Look through /etc/passwd and see what accounts are present (other than the system accounts and the participants). Look in /etc/passwd and /etc/group to find members of the abacus group. There's just guest.
>  So copy the private key to ~/.ssh/id_rsa, set the permissions correctly, and ssh guest@localhost. Bingo.

---

<advertisement>

If you like this kind of stuff, we participate in [capture-the-flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capture_The_Flag#Computer_security) competitions as the [sec.se (Security Stack Exchange) CTF team](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team) (see the meta post for organizational details). There's more web, reverse engineering and crypto involved than unix though.

Comment: Nice Gilles, I figured it out too!

Comment: @Gilles I did not see your solution until i did it. Thanks for keeping it on mouse over :)  Nice. And i guess i cant join your group. I lack reputations :) will grow up someday ;) and i like more of crypto stuff too. Ever laid hands on stego ??

Answer (score 2):

The original problem statement is here, http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/hack-unix/.

In looking at this problem, I do not believe there is any method for gaining access to the file via the permissions. After logging in:

```
$ cd /home/hacker-weekly/
$ ls -la
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   2 hacker-weekly hacker-weekly  4096 Nov 12  2012 .
drwxr-xr-x 556 root          root          20480 Sep 20 19:30 ..
-r--r-----   1 root          abacus          373 Nov 12  2012 abacus
```

From what I know of permissions (Unix) and filesystems there is no straightforward way to gain access to this file because of these permissions. The permissions are telling us that you either (1) have to gain access to root or (2) gain access to an account that has access to the group `abacus`.

#### Exploring the Group angle

In looking at  this group I noticed to following in the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files:

*/etc/passwd*

```
$ grep -E "ashwinscongo|guest|abacus" /etc/passwd
guest:x:1001:1001::/home/guest:/bin/sh
.guest:x:1436:1437::/home/.guest:/bin/bash
ashwinscongo:x:1544:1545::/home/ashwinscongo:/bin/bash
```

*/etc/group*

```
$ grep -E "ashwinscongo|guest|abacus" /etc/group
guest:x:1001:
abacus:x:1004:guest
.guest:x:1437:
ashwinscongo:x:1545:
```

So it would seem that we need to gain access to the `guest` account.

#### sudo?

We have no sudo privileges.

```
$ sudo -l
[sudo] password for ashwinscongo: 
Sorry, user ashwinscongo may not run sudo on ip-10-144-3-172
```

#### Logging into guest

I can only conceive of a frontal assault at this point so I tried the [top most 25 password from 2012](http://www.zdnet.com/top-25-common-attackable-passwords-stop-using-ninja-and-jesus-7000006373/), along with:

- guest
- abacus
- ab12d6H
- tseug
- Abacus

None of which worked.

#### Other angles?

1. Find an executable that has it's permissions such that it either (1) executes as root or (2) executes as guest (setuid/setgid files)!
2. Gain access to guest
3. Exploit a trust relationship of some sort for ssh? (ssh guest@localhost) angle?

#### Actual solution

It took a bit but I figured it out. My username is slmingol. Apparently Gilles figured it out too!

- http://www.hackerearth.com/users/slmingol/
- http://www.hackerearth.com/users/gilles/

If you poke around on the box looking for executables you'll find everything that you need. Now that I know how to do it it's best if you figure it out on your own.

The hint regarding permissions is relevant only in the sense that you need to gain privileges. The other clue you'll find if you google around is also apt about ssh'ing into the guest account. I encourage you to stick with it and don't cheat by looking at @Gilles clues/answer.

If you're really stuck I can give you some additional hints without spoiling it!

Comment: @slim thanks for the hints. I appreciate it that the answers werent given away. Hints are good enough :) I ll try not to look into giles's solution and go ahead myself

Comment: @0v3rc10ck3d - Good luck and don't give up. Let me know if you'd like an additional hint.

Comment: @slim : Sure :) I googled around a bit about ssh into guest accounts. I knew about the RSA keys with ssh. will try to exploit that.

Comment: @0v3rc10ck3d - continue to focus on the files on the system.

Comment: @slim : here is what i did. explored all the files in /usr/bin. Most of the executables were linux commands theere was one which wasnt. On running that file i got a  RSA private key. I copied that private key and replaced mine with it in my .ssh folder. I tried using -i option with SSH to use the modified private key and log into guest. again asks for password. Kinda stuck now :| just wondering abt the public key.

Comment: @slim Done ! feels good to  have done it. I changed the private key deleted my publickey(i still dnt know if that matters) did an ssh guest. got a message from ssh saying private key was too open. I changed the permission to read for root and the ssh worked ! THANK YOU. Got to learn a few many things :D

Comment: @0v3rc10ck3d - glad you figured it out!